# Double reload of the page when react app updates state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is the simpilfied version of my application setup. This is not the exact code - but should reproduce the undesired behavior I am grappling with.

```js
class App {
  state = { incidents: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    API.getIncidents().then(incidents => this.setState(incidents));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.incidents && <IncidentBanner />}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        )
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to load an incident banner link at the top of the page. The app loads up once, then the request completes, state is set, and the app reloads again - the entire page refreshes -which results in a flickering of the page, and generally bad user experience.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: After this.setState is called, the component must re-render with the new state. So it's once called with `incidents` being `null` and once with whatever value you fetch from your API.

Comment: Sounds like you want to avoid rendering any of the site (e.g. Home) until the incidents have finished loading to avoid a layout shift? (NOTE: I think saying its 'reloading' twice is misleading unless there's more going on than can be seen in this code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to avoid rendering any of the site (e.g. Home) until the incidents have finished loading to avoid a layout shift caused by the banner rendering? e.g.

```js
class App {
  state = { incidents: null, loading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    API.getIncidents()
        .then(data => this.setState({ incidents: data.incidents, loading: false }))
        .catch(() => this.setState({ loading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.incidents && <IncidentBanner />}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        )
      </>
    );
  }
}
```